# Batch syntax error with moving

Tags: windows, batch-file

i try to move a test.txt file from my current direction (desktop)
to the Program Files(x86) folder.
This is my current batch code:

```
@echo off
move %~dp0\test.txt %PROGRAMFILES(x86)%
pause
```

I added a pause to see what i get as "errors/results" and i see there in the cmd window, that it answers with

> Syntaxerror.

I even run the batch file as Admin, still same issue...

Any help/ideas? Need to create an installer with the help of batch.
Thanks

Now i got the problem to move a folder, i have the answer to move a file, however to move a folder, even with admin rights, it says acces denied...

Comment: if you use foldernames or filenames that could contain spaces, use quotes around them: `"move %~dp0\test.txt" "%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%"`

Comment: Used your suggestion, this is the answer:

Comment: “The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.”

Comment: I think @Stephan's comment has a typo: `move "%~dp0\test.txt" "%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%"` (notice the 1st dblquote).

Comment: @CristiFati you are right :)

Comment: There we go, thanks :D

Comment: It was actually only "%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%" who needed those " "

Comment: But i can't move folders :/ it says: Acces denied.

Comment: Even in Administrator mode...

Comment: Duplicate of [Acces denied by moving a folder to C: (admin rights) Batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045149/acces-denied-by-moving-a-folder-to-c-admin-rights-batch)

Answer (score 1):

Due the help of Stephand and CristiFati:

```
@echo off
move %~dp0\test.txt "%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%"
pause
```