# Why is access denied on moving a folder to program files folder with administrator privileges?

Tags: batch-file, admin, move

So I want to move a folder called `test` to the directory `"%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%"`.
However, even by running the batch file as administrator, it won't really move. I get the error message:

> Access denied.

This is my current batch file:

```
@echo off
move %~dp0test "%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%"
pause
```

`%~dp0` is for the current directory of the folder (desktop in my case).

So how can I solve this issue to move the folder `test` to `"%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%"` without the access denied error?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: can you manually move it?  ALso, is UAC turned on?

Comment: @Spencer4134 So how can i solve this issue, to move the folder test to "%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%" since i get the error Acces denied.

Comment: @DiscipleMichael Yes.  UAC? Side info: I'm currently on the super-admin account. So i have the highest rights with this account...

Comment: Well, it is normal that you wouldn't be able to run the bat successfully without choosing "run as admin" due to windows restriction of the program files and  ...files(x86) directories.  However, it isn't normal that it still fails when you do.  Could you post the security for both the (x86) folder and the test folder/

Comment: Doesn't matter what super admin account you are using.  You still need launch the batch file with Run As Admin.

Comment: Yes but some "admin" accounts dont have rights to write into several directories, even with RAA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The access denied error message could be caused in your case with running the batch file already with administrator privileges by

- a file in directory to move being currently opened by an application, or
- the directory to move is the current directory of a running process (batch file), or
- the administrator account has no permissions on your desktop folder which is very unlikely but possible as it is the folder in your user profile and not in user profile of the administrator account.

In the first two cases it is not possible to delete the specified directory and a sharing access denied error message is the result. So not the permissions in target folder are perhaps the problem here, but the sharing access permissions on source folder and their files.

By the way: Better use `move "%~dp0test" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%"` as path of batch file could contain a space even if this is not the case currently with batch file being in your Windows desktop folder on Windows Vista or later as long as your user name does not contain a space character.

Comment: Thank you. Actually a .pdf file was opened, needed to shut it down via task kill... Thank you